# What did Bohm exactly mean when he said that mind and matter were the same?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, materialism

In 1990, the physicist David Bohm published a paper named "A new theory of the relationship of mind and matter" promoting a "panpsychist" theory of consciousness based on Bohm's interpretation of quantum mechanics."

Bohm's words: "everything material is also mental and everything mental is also material, but there are many more infinitely subtle levels of matter than we are aware of".

What does this exactly mean? Did Bohm mean that all what we imagine is real/physical? If yes, wouldn't that mean that every world/universe we can imagine (even if inconsistent) would physically exist, just as our universe? Was he saying that the universe is fundamentally information (in form of our mental states)?

Comment: It does not mean that "all that we imagine" is real, it means that everything physical also has some mental capacity. What we imagine is not the "mental", it is what imagines it (mind, consciousness) that is. He is saying that even at the most basic level matter carries some rudimentary form of consciousness. It does not mean "universe is fundamentally information" (that does not make sense, information is a representation of something else), and it certainly does not need to be in the form of *our* mental states. Forms of the "mental" can be as different from each other as forms of matter.

Comment: Bohm and J Krishnamurti [talked](http://bohmkrishnamurti.com/bohm-consciousness-seminars/)  dozens of times over 25 years. It would help to illuminate this question if looked from that angle... And then perhaps rephrase "mind" as "consciousness" and "matter" as "this (seemingly material) world"

Comment: @Conifold: "universe is fundamentally information" That is actually a widespread take, begun with Feynman's mentor Wheel who proposed his 'It From Bit' doctrine, and more generally developed as Digital Physics

Comment: @CriglCragl That is only a widespread shorthand, a misleading one if taken literally, but typical in merging representations with what they represent. Wheeler's it from bit, for example, is based on "*multitude of existences, each characterized, directly or indirectly, by the soliciting and receiving of answers to yes-no questions*". The bits of information are only ciphers for the askers of the questions and their activities. It is similar in all other "informational" proposals, information merely represents something else, something that can act.

Comment: @Conifold: I picture it a network of Shannon channels, lile Indra's Net. "information is a representation of something else" Exactly that. There is only the information about things propagating, no things. I am perplexed that you find that controversial.

Comment: @CriglCragl What I find controversial, and in extreme forms, like Tegmark's, unintelligible is that (causally inert) abstraction,  like information or "structure", is supposed to *do* the propagating and much besides. There are no things that information is "about", but there is a host of other things required to make it move. Not only is it hardly "only information", but information is rather a side show to the actual metaphysical furniture, often extravagant. Wheeler is, at least, explicit about his acting observers, as Plato was about his living and breathing Forms.

Comment: @Conifold: I think of building a computer in Conway's 'game of life'. Life as a computer that can replicate. Minds as strange loops able to analyse themselves & adjust in response.